# jquery: How to detect if a form button was triggered directly or indirectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a form with some elements and one or more submit buttons.
I have an event handler attached to the submit button via jquery to listen for "click".

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

$("body").on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    // explicitOriginalTarget is unsupported in IE!!
    if (e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget === this) {
        alert('direct');
        return false;
    }

    alert('indirect');
    return false;
});
```

[Example on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRFwP/2/)

This handler will be triggered by either clicking the button with the mouse or hitting the enter key when the text-input or the button is highlighted.

**Question**: How can I detect (**cross-browser**, including IE10+) if the handler was triggered by hitting the enter key when the cursor is in the text-input or by direct click via mouse or enter when tabbed to the button?

Solutions without additional handlers for keypress/keyup are preferred ;-)

Comment: How about this: [jquery event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)  it tells you what key code was used for the event.

Comment: As great as that would have been, I tried it using e.type (click or keycode) and e.which (value) but it kept coming back as type: click and which: 1 (left click), regardless of whether I clicked submit with the mouse or hit enter while in the textbox :(

Comment: Only keyboard events produce keyCodes, click and submit does not.

Comment: What about checking the focus of the textbox?  Not sure if the submit button will steal focus if it is clicked.

Comment: yes, I tried e.type und e.originalEvent.type as well as e.which and e.originalEvent.which before to no avail.
Also document.activeElement will be the text-input in Firefox but the submit-button in IE when triggering the "indirect" click

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell, you might need to go down the route @adeneo published below.

Comment: @J.S. - how about just reading my answer below, which solves the issue in two different ways. I would go for the first one, but whatever floats your goat.

Comment: @adeno Sorry for not posting my comment to your answer before commenting here. Sure I read your answer and commented on it. But both your solutions fail when I tab to the submit from the text field and hit enter then, they both give me "indirect" as result.